# JavaScript - select a random page from directory

Tags: javascript, html, random, html-helper

I'm developing a webpage but I need a JS script which selects a random page from a directory. At the moment I have this script;

```
    <!-- Hide this script from old browsers --

var links = new Array(10) 
links[0] = "anal.html" 
links[1] = "brr-fail.htm" 
links[2] = "anal.html" 
links[3] = "brr-fail.htm" 
links[4] = "anal.html" 
links[5] = "brr-fail.htm" 
links[6] = "anal.html" 
links[7] = "brr-fail.htm" 
links[8] = "anal.html" 
links[9] = "brr-fail.htm" 
links[10] = "anal.html" 
function go() { 
var a = 1+Math.round(Math.random()*10) 
var i = a 
location = links[i] 
} 
// -- End Hiding Here -->

</script>
```

(Don't worry, it isn't gay porn - meme)

As you can see, it is kinda complicated, and sometimes it brings up an "undefined" page error. Is there any way to make it select a random page from the whole directory? Say something like;

www.urlhere.co.uk/memes/random/

Thanks guys

Comment: JS is client side and you can't list directories on server with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math random produces a value between `0` and `1`, if you multiply with 10, you get number from `0.0` to `9.9`, and if you round that, you get number from `0` to `10`. So you don't need to add 1 to it, that would result in 11 in some cases, wich you don't have, since the `undefined`. Simply use:

```
var a = Math.round(Math.random()*10); // {0-10}
```

**Edit:** corrected my wrong 1st answer

**Note:** actually would not result a standard distribution of random numbers, since 0 and 10 would only result if, `Math.random()` is 0.0 - 0.049... (0) and 0.95 - 0.99... (10) You can even the odds by this:

```
var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*11); // {0-10}
```

This way a whole decimal range (x.0-x.9) floored down.

Comment: The asker needs random values in the range of 0 to 10. Since `Math.random()` is never equals or greater than 1, then every number produced by `Math.random() * 11` is smaller than 11, so `Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)` will result numbers 0 to 10.

Comment: Ah, looks like I shall be needing a PHP script instead then... Hmmmmmm, tricky

Comment: In PHP you have a function for this: `$a = rand(0, 10);` GL!

Answer (score 2):

You're out of index, you should do:

```
var a = Math.round(Math.random()*10);
```

Because the 0th element of your links array won't trigger due the 1+random..

Edit:

```
var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
```

Comment: This code's chance of resulting in `a = 0` or `a = 10` is half that of  `a` being any other value between the two.

Answer (score 1):

you're missing `;` delimiters on the end of lines and

```
function randInt(max, min) {
    return (min || 0) + Math.floor(Math.random()*(max+1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the corrections guys. Is there an easier way to do this though? Instead of listing all the pages, could I have some sort of basic script which will randomly select a page? A little bit of AI.

Comment: Only if the page is selected server-side as without some sort of index of all the pages, the JS will not know which pages exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
var links = new Array(10) 
links[0] = "anal.html" ;
links[1] = "brr-fail.htm" ;
links[2] = "anal.html" ;
links[3] = "brr-fail.htm" ;
links[4] = "anal.html" ;
links[5] = "brr-fail.htm" ;
links[6] = "anal.html" ;
links[7] = "brr-fail.htm" ;
links[8] = "anal.html" ;
links[9] = "brr-fail.htm" ;
links[10] = "anal.html" ;
function go() { 
var a= Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
var i = a;
location = links[i] ;
}
```